# error in opening zip file on WAR file deployment

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I developed a web application which uses xalan-2.7.1.jar and using maven for dependency management. When I deploy the WAR file in Tomcat server I'm getting the following error,

```
WARNING: Failed to process JAR [jar:file:/D:/proj/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/avis.com/WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.xalan-xalan-2.7.1.jar!/] for TLD files
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:136)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:73)
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

if you are working in linux server and you sent the war file thorugh SCP command or any file transfer tools from your local to the server, may the file is corrupted due to losing some packets so check the size of war file in your local and the size on the server.if there is a difference upload it again.

[image: compare the size of corrupted file to the original]